# Storing input from user into linked list using array

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

So I'm trying to get input from user and store it in linked list, using array (every 5 chars a new linked list is created). After getting EOF I want to print the input (actually print the arrays in each linked list)
here is my code:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5



 typedef struct charNode {
    int arr[MAX];
    struct charNode *next;
} charNode;


void addNode();
void printAll();

 

    int main(){
   int c,i;
   charNode *head=malloc(sizeof(charNode));
   charNode *current=head;

 while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
  while(i<MAX){
  current->arr[i++]=c;
 }
 i=0;
 addNode(current);
 }
 printAll(head);


 return 0;
 }
 void addNode(charNode *current){
   struct charNode *link = (struct charNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct charNode));
     current->next =link;
     link->next = NULL;
   current=current->next;
 } 

 void printAll(charNode *head){
  int j=0;
  while(head->next!=NULL){
   while(j<MAX){
    printf("\n %d \t",head->arr[j++]);
   }
    printAll(head->next);
  }
  return;
 }
```

and I'm getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error..

Answer (score 2):

This is **Undefined behavior**:

```
int c,i;
charNode *head=malloc(sizeof(charNode));
charNode *current=head;

while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
  while(i<MAX){
    current->arr[i++]=c;
  }
```

since you are using `i` uninitialized to access your array, which could produce the Segmentation fault.

---

Change this:

```
printf("\n %d \t",head->arr[j++]);
```

to this:

```
printf("\n %c \t",head->arr[j++]);
```

so that you print characters, instead of numbers.

---

Simply initialize `i` to 0 for a start, happy debugging! =)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Initialization solved the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" problem, and it manages to print something to the terminal, but it doesn't print the chars. It print 
"10
 10
10
10
10
0
0
0
0
0"

Comment: @AntonFreid you are welcome. I updated my answer. Hope that helps. If you feel you have other questions, post a new question! ;) If you want, *accept* my answer.

Comment: Hey @gsamaras, thank you again for trying to help me, changing the printf function like you said,  didn't help, because the array in struct is type int. I feeling like the problem is with the  pointers, because it prints me integers and not characters. I think it may be printing addresses but I don't know. Also debugging doesn't help, because I get the input from a file and I don't know why, but the debugger thinks the input is a command

Comment: @AntonFreid maybe. However note that with `%c`, 10 will be converted to its ASCII characters, which will be printed, but not all ASCII codes are visible.

Comment: @AntonFreid why do you store your chars as ints?

Comment: Because EOF is represented as -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    char c;
    charNode *head=malloc(sizeof(charNode));
    charNode *current=head;

    int i = 0;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        getchar();
        while(i<MAX){
            current->arr[i++]=c;
        }
        i=0;
        addNode(&current);
    }

    printAll(head);


    return 0;
}

void addNode(charNode **current){
    struct charNode *link = malloc(sizeof(struct charNode));
    link->next = NULL;
    (*current)->next =link;
    *current=(*current)->next;
} 

void printAll(charNode *head){
    int j=0;
    if(head!=NULL){
        while(j<MAX){
            printf("%c\n",head->arr[j++]);
        }
        if(head->next != NULL)
            printAll(head->next);
    }
}
```

I changed your code a bit. Especially take a good look at addNode(). Now it works correctly